# Getting a Windows Docker Container running with .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: python, windows, docker, gitlab, cicd

I am trying to get a Windows docker container running with Python3 using my Gitlab pipeline script. But it seems that the yaml configuration below only starts a Linux docker container. How can I configure my .yml file to start a Windows image with the latest version of python?

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: python:latest
```

Comment: Windows runners are not available on gitlab.com shared runners -- To run on Windows, you need to self-host your runner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the linux version of the python container because GitLab's shared runners use linux. Due to how containers work, they share the kernel of the host machine, so a linux runner can't "host" a windows container - it simply doesn't have the kernel instructions to run it.

If you want to run a windows docker image, you will need to have a windows server [with a supported version](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#supported-windows-versions) that you're self hosting. You will also need to ensure that the windows docker container you're using works properly.

All of this having been said - if you're trying to use python, just run it in Linux. It seems like there are vanishingly few reasons you would need python to be running specifically on windows for your CI/CD, but if you let us know what they are we may be able to help.

Comment: Thank you, I am compiling my python script into a binary Windows executable using Nuitka (a python compiler). I just assumed I wouldn't able to compile a Windows executable from Linux, but I haven't looked into it.

Comment: Got it. Yeah, for Nuitka it looks like it inherits the c compilation from the host so you'd either have to use WINE to run a windows-like compile within linux or use a windows docker container. You've found one of those vanishing reasons :).  That having been said, it looks like using WINE with pyinstaller or Nuitka isn't that complex, so it may be worth looking into that before trying to get a windows docker image running.

Comment: Awesome, okay thanks for the guidance! Might try using WINE :)

Answer (score 3):

There is one other answer and that is [Pywine](https://github.com/webcomics/pywine). It emulates a windows inside of a linux for python.

It therfore is:

A docker runner than opens another docker runner that emulatates windows that can be used to solve this. Down below you will find my setup for this:

This is by far not the best setup but it works for me. As a docker image i am using tobix/pywine:3.9. If you find a better way please tell me. I would be very happy to improve the setup.

```yaml
image: python:3.9

# Change pip's cache directory to be inside the project directory since we can
# only cache local items.
variables:
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"
  
stages:
  - "Static Code Analysis"
  - "test"
  - "deploy"

cache:
  paths:
    - .cache/pip
    - venv/

before_script:
  - python3.9 -V  # Print out python version for debugging
  - python3.9 -m pip install virtualenv
  - virtualenv venv
  - source venv/bin/activate

Black Linter:
  when: always
  stage: "Static Code Analysis"
  tags:
    - pi
  script:
    - pip install black
    - black  --check --diff ./
  allow_failure: true

Flake Linter:
  when: always
  stage: "Static Code Analysis"
  tags:
    - pi
  script:
    - pip install flake8
    - flake8 --statistics
  allow_failure: true

Type-test:
  when: always
  image: tobix/pywine:3.9
  tags:
    - win-docker
  stage: "Static Code Analysis"
  before_script:
    - . /opt/mkuserwineprefix
    - wine /opt/wineprefix/drive_c/Python39/Python.exe -v
    - wine /opt/wineprefix/drive_c/Python39/Python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
    - wine /opt/wineprefix/drive_c/Python39/Python.exe -m pip install wheel --no-warn-script-location
    - wine /opt/wineprefix/drive_c/Python39/Python.exe -m pip install -Ur requirements/test.txt --no-warn-script-location
  script:
    - wine /opt/wineprefix/drive_c/Python39/Python.exe -m mypy . --warn-redundant-casts --warn-unused-ignores --show-column-numbers --pretty --install-types --non-interactive
  allow_failure: true

test:
  needs: []
  tags:
    - win-docker
  image: tobix/pywine:3.9
  before_script:
    - . /opt/mkuserwineprefix
    - wine /opt/wineprefix/drive_c/Python39/Python.exe -v
    - wine /opt/wineprefix/drive_c/Python39/Python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools --no-warn-script-location
    - wine /opt/wineprefix/drive_c/Python39/Python.exe -m pip install wheel --no-warn-script-location
    - wine /opt/wineprefix/drive_c/Python39/Python.exe -m pip install -Ur requirements/test.txt --no-warn-script-location
  script:
    - wine /opt/wineprefix/drive_c/Python39/Python.exe -m pytest test/ --junitxml=/report.xml --cov=./
    - wine /opt/wineprefix/drive_c/Python39/Python.exe -m coverage report
    - wine /opt/wineprefix/drive_c/Python39/Python.exe -m coverage xml
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit: report.xml
      cobertura: coverage.xml

pyinstall:
  stage: deploy
  image: tobix/pywine:3.9
  retry: 2
  tags:
    - win-docker
  before_script:
      - . /opt/mkuserwineprefix
      - wine /opt/wineprefix/drive_c/Python39/Python.exe -v
      - wine /opt/wineprefix/drive_c/Python39/Python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools pyinstaller
      - wine /opt/wineprefix/drive_c/Python39/Python.exe -m pip install wheel --no-warn-script-location
      - wine /opt/wineprefix/drive_c/Python39/Python.exe -m pip install -Ur requirements/base.txt --no-warn-script-location

  script:
    - wine /opt/wineprefix/drive_c/Python39/Scripts/pyinstaller.exe main.spec --clean
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "dist/*.exe"
  rules:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

Please note that everything I didn't need to run on windows runs in an normal docker container to be more efficient.

Comment: Cool , thank you!