# Can I use Docker to check in a Gitlab pipeline whether my code compiles on Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, gitlab

I am using Gitlab to build and test my code. And I want to check whether the code compiles on Linux and Windows. But I am unsure whether this is possible, i.e., starting Windows through Docker on a UNIX machine. This is my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - compile_linux
  - compile_windows

compile_linux:
  stage: compile_linux
  image: ubuntu:jammy
  script:
    - cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -S . -B cmake-build-release -Wno-dev


compile_windows:
  stage: compile_windows
  image: cirrusci/windowsservercore:cmake-2022.06.23
  script:
    - cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -S . -B cmake-build-release -Wno-dev
```

The two stages succeeded, but I am not sure whether I am doing the right thing here.

Is this correct? If not, what do I need to do, or is it even possible to do what I want to do?
I found this question: [Getting a Windows Docker Container running with .gitlab-ci.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70207598/getting-a-windows-docker-container-running-with-gitlab-ci-yml)
But our institute is hosting Gitlab ourselves, but on a UNIX. So the shared runner issue should not be a problem. But I don't understand the other answer there, it sounds like what I try to achieve is not possible?